# Asymptotic expansion of $\exp(-ax)\,\cosh(bx)$ or $\exp(-ax)\,\sinh(bx)$

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to understand the behaviour of

$$\exp(-ax)\,\cosh(bx)$$

or

$$\exp(-ax)\,\sinh(bx)$$

for large $x$, provided that $a,b>0$ and $a>b$ or $a<b$.

Comment: The Maple command $$simplify(asympt(exp(-ax)*cosh(b*x), x, 2)) \,assuming a > 0, b > 0, a > b  $$ produces $$1/2\,{{\rm e}^{bx-{\it ax}}}+1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-bx-{\it ax}}} $$ and the command $$simplify(asympt(exp(-ax)*cosh(b*x), x, 2)) \,assuming a > 0, b > 0, a < b $$ produces $$1/2\,{{\rm e}^{bx-{\it ax}}}+1/2\,{{\rm e}^{-bx-{\it ax}}}. $$

Answer (score 2):

Expand the hyperbolic function as exponentials, i.e. write the first exoression as $$\exp(-ax)\,\cosh(bx) =  \frac{1}{2}\exp((b-a)x) - \frac{1}{2}exp(-(a+b)x)$$
From this you can read off the expansion depending on signs and order of $a,b$. The second expression is handled the same way.